# jQuery selectbox plugin to open upwards when at the bottom of screen?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

currently i've ran into following problem:

I am using following plugin for nice selectboxes: http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

It's working perfectly, except the situation, when the dropdown is positioned near the bottom of the screen - I need to display the options above the selectbox instead of classic behavior (below) in this case.

I'm trying to workaround the _openSelectbox function, but still without success...

Any ideas?

Comment: please place code as an example or create a jsfiddle